# is there a way to have make check the prerequisites but ignore their time stamps and always execute the recipe?

Tags: makefile

In other words, the prerequisites must exist, but once they do, always consider the target out of date.  I thought maybe I could use the FORCE trick, but since you can't rely on order of evaluation of prerequisites, I wasn't sure how to make that work. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Make the target `.PHONY`

```
.PHONY: somefile

somefile: someotherfile
    cat $^ > $@

someotherfile:
    echo hi > $@
```